# Efficient way to display German character 'ß' as is on browser instead of 'ss'

Tags: html, text, unicode, fonts, character

I have a German site and the character `ß` does not seem to display as it is when the text has uppercase text transform in CSS. It displays as `ss` instead.

I checked some solutions and I have read that it is the font not supporting German character but I am not sure why the issue only occurs when the text is transformed to uppercase.

Currently, I have the solution JS and CSS solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('h1, p, a, strong, b, em, i, label').each(function(){
        html = jQuery(this).html();
        if (jQuery(this).children().length == 0 && html.indexOf("no-uppercase") < 0) {
            jQuery(this).html( jQuery(this).html().replace( /ß/g, '<span class="no-uppercase">ß</span>' ) );
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.no-uppercase {
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

But I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to have the character display correctly.

Comment: *SS* is indeed a valid uppercase form of *ß*. Every German will understand it and not notice anything wrong. If you leave *ß* there, amidst uppercase letters it *will* look weird. There's an uppercase ß again: ẞ which is also valid. (And, if SS is ambiguous, you can also use SZ, but that's very, very rare.) So I wonder why are you even trying to do this. No German will be bothered by ß turning to SS.

Comment: For some weird reason, my client is. Not sure why.

Comment: The only true solution is to actually write "original" German content. Because what are you going to do with words that contain "ss" that are _not_ actually an eszet? Step 1: properly written unicode content. Step 2: make sure you use a webfont that supports all content codepoints, including upperface. A good way to verify this is use use Adobe's "blank" as fallback font, which will show (unsurprisingly) blank space instead of letters if your real font doesn't support something. Step 3: there is no step 3.

Comment: The answer to why your client is bothered with the SS, is because there are german words wich after the ß have another S so it looks like SSS, like "BARFUSSSCHUHE" and it should be "BARFUßSCHUHE"